# Display Jquery Slick option on media screen

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, slick.js

I'm beginner in training!

I have a slick Slider on my header.
I have Dots:true and arrow on my slider with JQuery.

I want a display:none on my Dots when screen are <1000px.

I'm Starting Jquery so I dont know how to put a media queries on my app.js.

For now, I have this on my JQuery:

```
$('.hp-header-slider').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        arrows: false,
    });
```

And I put media queries on my css but didn't work.

```
 /* PHONE - MOBIL - TAB  */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){

  .hp-header-slider .slick-dotted ul.slick-list li.slick-dots{
    display: none !important;
  }
```

I don't find the doc for media on JQuery like Slike-Slider .. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick have built-in responsive option for this:
For example:

```js
$('.responsive').slick({
dots: true,
infinite: false,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 4,
responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      infinite: true,
      dots: true
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    }
  }
  // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
  // settings: "unslick"
  // instead of a settings object
]
});
```